# Market Power in microeconomic theory

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, academic-graduate, education-economics

What does the term **Market Power** mean in microeconomic theory

Comment: Could you make please make your question more clear? Googling the term gave several definitions that seem fine to me. If you have trouble understanding a definition let us know which part confuses you.

Comment: I downvoted this because there is no (correctly phrased) question (one that uses proper English), and there is a lack of evidence of what research @Sanjay has done in order to solve this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In competition policy (part of microeconomics), market power is often defined as the ability of a firm to raise and maintain prices above the levels that would prevail under competitive conditions (with obvious adjustments if the market power is held by a buyer).  Having market power does not necessarily mean it is used or abused, just that it can be

See for example:

- https://stats.oecd.org/glossary/detail.asp?ID=3256
- https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/284400/oft415.pdf